# Add logo Image on 2-3 rows in sheet while exporting excel from datatable In javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, datatable, export

I google this this everywhere but i didn't got any solution.

```
var detailedTable = $('#detailedReport').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "dataSrc": '',
    scrollY: '330px',
    scrollX: '360px',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    select: true,
    colReorder: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Download Report',
            className: 'btn btn-primary form-control',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'excel', text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Excel', titleAttr: 'CSV', className: 'btn btn-primary form-control' },
                { extend: 'csv', text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> CSV', titleAttr: 'CSV', className: 'btn btn-primary form-control' },
                { extend: 'pdf', text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF', titleAttr: 'PDF', className: 'btn btn-primary form-control' },
                { extend: 'print', text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print', titleAttr: 'Print', className: 'btn btn-primary form-control' },
                //'copy',
            ]
        }
    ],
    columns: detailedColumn             
});
```

[image]

But I want to add an image or company logo in top of two some rows according to image above table headings.

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA - your question is based on using [FastExcel](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel) for Laravel. This question uses a completely different library - [DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) - which uses JavaScript and a completely different Excel library. The 2 questions are not the same - and the solutions would be very different.

Comment: I think you need to use `headerCallback` function. [This answer might be help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589855/append-js-data-to-a-table-header-update-header-with-that-item)